# How to report the result of a mathematical approach?

Tags: sentence-construction

Consider:

we have several approaches for calculating an expression. One of them is *T1*. Using this approach, we derived some expression for an mathematical problem. For instance, and optimization problem. Now, I want to generate a report that must be submitted to my teacher. It must be formal, articulate, and such that does not strike to a Native as odd!

Compare:

> 1. In the case of *T1*, deriving a closed-form expression for *Eq.1* requires solving a complicated integral.
> 2. In the case of *T1*, deriving a closed-form expression for *Eq.1* requires a complicated integral to be solved.
> 3. In the case of *T1*, closed-form expression of *Eq.1* requires a complicated integral to be solved during the derivation process.
> 4. In the case of *T1*, closed-form expression of *Eq.1* requires solving a complicated integral within the derivation process.

The above sentences are all that I can construct with my little knowledge. Can you help me to improve my report. My key purpose is to create a succinct sentence which stands out this point:

**solving the complicated Integral is crucial for reaching to the closed-from expression**

Comment: I come from a math background, and I like number one the best. I can't really justify it though.

Answer (score 1):

Your first sentence sounds great! It is succinct, and uses the simplest verb tenses, which is almost always preferred in writing like this.

Comment: Agreed - the meaning of all of them is virtually identical, but #1 phrases things as "X requires Y", which is nice and simple.  #2 is almost as good, being "X requires something to be *Y*ed"